# How do I recreate this color overlay/design in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, overlay

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see its mild tones of a dark cyan and faded pink on different shadows/tones of color but still preserving some little bits of color. Not sure how to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

- **Menu Select** > **Color Range** > **HighLights***

  - From the dropdown menu decide which color area will be affected
  - Moving *Fuzziness* and *Range* you can define how big the colored area will be

[image: Colorarea]

- With this selection, make a **Color Fill Layer**

[image: PHOTO]

[image: Color Range]

[image: End]

[Photo](https://unsplash.com/photos/dP6g1YJWQcA) from unsplash.com

- Make two **Fill Color Layers** with *Midtones* and *Highlights* selections to get the bi-color effect
- Edit and adjust the **Color Fill Layer Mask**

[image: Midtones and highlights]

[Photo](https://unsplash.com/photos/_h5yGdue66o) from unsplash.com

Comment: Looks like the OP images use "step one" twice on a color original: one for highest highlights and one more in the mid-tones with a tighter range.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after I answer. Well, the technique is the same.

Comment: Exactly, only meant to clarify for the OP

Comment: @Yorik Fixed at the end of the answer